# Facebook API not getting response for non register app user

Tags: facebook-graph-api

When I logged in by user who has created it gives return post but for others user.it is not working.

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => 'xxx',
    'secret' => 'xxx', 
    'cookie' => true
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();
$par = array();
$par['scope'] = "status_update user_about_me user_status,user_post,user_stream";

if ($user) {
    $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
    try {
        // Proceed knowing you have a user who is logged in and authenticated
        // Get Feed
        $feed = $facebook->api('/me/feed');
        // Get User Profile
        $profile = $facebook->api('/me');
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
        $user = null;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you expect, and "not working" is not a good error description, but you can´t get data of users who did not authorize your App. So the code after "`if ($user)`" will not be called in that case.

Btw, you may want to fix your scope parameter. Some commas are missing and there is no permission called `user_stream` or `status_update`.